# Историческое обоснование явлений современного русского языка

Tags: орфография, словообразование, история, морфемика, правила

Ниже приведен список орфограмм современного русского языка. Нужно отследить, в результате каких исторических изменений сформировались данные правила (но все мы знаем, что это лишь наблюдения ученых, а причина оных кроется в истории). К примеру:

> **Беглые гласные.** Гласные *о* и *е* современного русского языка, чередующиеся с нулем звука при формообразовании и словообразовании.
>   Например, отец – отца.  Это объясняется редуцированными гласными в
>   старославянском языке: *ъ* (сверхкраткий гласный
>   О) и *ь* (сверхкраткий гласный Е). В слове *отьць*, в корне *ь* стоит перед
>   слогом с редуцированным в слабой позиции, поэтому он занимает сильную
>   позицию (подчеркнут). В слове *отьца* имеет слабую позицию, т. к. находится
>   перед слогом с гласным полного образования. Со второй половины X века
>   редуцированные гласные утрачиваются. Гласные в сильной позиции
>   переходят в звуки полного образования, а в слабой позиции исчезают.

Вот я разобрал первую орфограмму. Остановился на четвертой. Точного разбора не прошу, но не могли бы вы намекнуть на то, где мне искать. Например, падение редуцированных или принцип звукового сингармонизма и т. д. и т. п. 
[image: Вопросы]

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но что ж так небрежно написан!

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите в учебнике http://www.speakrus.ru/mix/other/ivanov_potikha_1985.pdf
Исторический комментарий к занятиям ро русскому языку в средней школе.

Там  разбираются многие темы, связанные с обоснованием орфографических правил.

Comment: Sibylla большое спасибо

Comment: Там ничего нет почти

Comment: Почему нет? Вы невнимательно читали. Очень многие случаи - следствие падения редуцированных, изменений фонетики.

Answer (score 4):

После утраты редуцированных происходит упрощение групп согласных и связанное с ней появление сочетаний из трех согласных в одном слоге. Такие сочетания несвойственны русской речи, потому что при произношении неизбежно происходит их упрощение за счет выпадения одного и даже двух согласных. Эти изменения отражаются на письме, происходит разрыв родственных связей слов и появление новых корневых слов. Например:

Бедрьцевая(кость)- берцовая, ср. бедро; гърньчаръ- гончар, ср. горн; 
Дьбряньскъ- Д’брян’ск - Брянск; ср. дебри; Пльсковъ - Псков; 
верт-мя(ср. веретено) - время;плед-мя(ср.: плодиться) - племя. 
Но часто писцы сохраняли традиционное написание, соответствующее их фонетическому составу и не отражающее изменений звуков. Так возникло несоответствие произношения написанию, которое получило название «непроизносимые согласные». В современном русском языке непроизносимые согласные обозначаются на письме в следующих сочетаниях:

стн с непроизносимым [т] - участник (участие);

здн с непроизносимым [д] - поздний (опоздать)

стл с непроизносимым[т] - завистливый (зависть)

стц, здц с непроизносимым[т], [д] истца (истец), под уздцы (узда)

рдц с непроизносимым[д]сердце

лнц с непроизносимым[л]солнце

вств с непроизносимым[в] безмолвствовать (молва)